# DSE Graph - Host did not respond in a timely fashion

Tags: graph, titan, gremlin, tinkerpop

Gremlin console seems to connect correctly, but it replies "Host did not respond in a timely fashion" after any query.

Already checked:
- remote.yaml
- netstat --listen | grep 8182    (returns nothing)

Gremlin lines:

```
plugin activated: tinkerpop.tinkergraph
plugin activated: tinkerpop.server
plugin activated: tinkerpop.utilities
gremlin> :remote connect tinkerpop.server conf/remote.yaml
==>Configured localhost/127.0.0.1:8182
gremlin> :> 1+1
Host did not respond in a timely fashion - check the server status and submit again.
```

Stack trace:

```
org.apache.tinkerpop.gremlin.groovy.plugin.RemoteException: Host did not respond in a timely fashion - check the server status and submit again.
        at org.apache.tinkerpop.gremlin.console.groovy.plugin.DriverRemoteAcceptor.submit(DriverRemoteAcceptor.java:174)
        at org.codehaus.groovy.vmplugin.v7.IndyInterface.selectMethod(IndyInterface.java:228)
        at org.apache.tinkerpop.gremlin.console.commands.SubmitCommand.execute(SubmitCommand.groovy:41)
        at org.codehaus.groovy.vmplugin.v7.IndyInterface.selectMethod(IndyInterface.java:228)
        at org.codehaus.groovy.tools.shell.Shell.execute(Shell.groovy:104)
        at org.codehaus.groovy.tools.shell.Groovysh.super$2$execute(Groovysh.groovy)
        at sun.reflect.GeneratedMethodAccessor15.invoke(Unknown Source)
        at sun.reflect.DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.java:43)
        at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:498)
        at org.codehaus.groovy.reflection.CachedMethod.invoke(CachedMethod.java:93)
        at groovy.lang.MetaMethod.doMethodInvoke(MetaMethod.java:325)
        at groovy.lang.MetaClassImpl.invokeMethod(MetaClassImpl.java:1212)
        at org.codehaus.groovy.runtime.ScriptBytecodeAdapter.invokeMethodOnSuperN(ScriptBytecodeAdapter.java:132)
        at org.codehaus.groovy.tools.shell.Groovysh.executeCommand(Groovysh.groovy:259)
        at org.apache.tinkerpop.gremlin.console.GremlinGroovysh.execute(GremlinGroovysh.groovy:75)
        at org.codehaus.groovy.tools.shell.Shell.leftShift(Shell.groovy:122)
        at org.codehaus.groovy.tools.shell.ShellRunner.work(ShellRunner.groovy:95)
        at org.codehaus.groovy.tools.shell.InteractiveShellRunner.super$2$work(InteractiveShellRunner.groovy)
        at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke0(Native Method)
        at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(NativeMethodAccessorImpl.java:62)
        at sun.reflect.DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.java:43)
        at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:498)
        at org.codehaus.groovy.reflection.CachedMethod.invoke(CachedMethod.java:93)
        at groovy.lang.MetaMethod.doMethodInvoke(MetaMethod.java:325)
        at groovy.lang.MetaClassImpl.invokeMethod(MetaClassImpl.java:1212)
        at org.codehaus.groovy.runtime.ScriptBytecodeAdapter.invokeMethodOnSuperN(ScriptBytecodeAdapter.java:132)
        at org.codehaus.groovy.runtime.ScriptBytecodeAdapter.invokeMethodOnSuper0(ScriptBytecodeAdapter.java:152)
        at org.codehaus.groovy.tools.shell.InteractiveShellRunner.work(InteractiveShellRunner.groovy:124)
        at org.codehaus.groovy.tools.shell.ShellRunner.run(ShellRunner.groovy:59)
        at org.codehaus.groovy.tools.shell.InteractiveShellRunner.super$2$run(InteractiveShellRunner.groovy)
        at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke0(Native Method)
        at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(NativeMethodAccessorImpl.java:62)
        at sun.reflect.DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.java:43)
        at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:498)
        at org.codehaus.groovy.reflection.CachedMethod.invoke(CachedMethod.java:93)
        at groovy.lang.MetaMethod.doMethodInvoke(MetaMethod.java:325)
        at groovy.lang.MetaClassImpl.invokeMethod(MetaClassImpl.java:1212)
        at org.codehaus.groovy.runtime.ScriptBytecodeAdapter.invokeMethodOnSuperN(ScriptBytecodeAdapter.java:132)
        at org.codehaus.groovy.runtime.ScriptBytecodeAdapter.invokeMethodOnSuper0(ScriptBytecodeAdapter.java:152)
        at org.codehaus.groovy.tools.shell.InteractiveShellRunner.run(InteractiveShellRunner.groovy:83)
        at org.codehaus.groovy.vmplugin.v7.IndyInterface.selectMethod(IndyInterface.java:228)
        at org.apache.tinkerpop.gremlin.console.Console.<init>(Console.groovy:174)
        at org.codehaus.groovy.vmplugin.v7.IndyInterface.selectMethod(IndyInterface.java:228)
        at org.apache.tinkerpop.gremlin.console.Console.main(Console.groovy:361)
gremlin>
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

When you install DSE, Graph service listens in the local network interface (eg. 10.x.x.x, not the loopback 127.0.0.1).

This means you need to edit the Gremlin Console YAML and point it to 10.x.x.x.

Comment: Note also that though this command will typically succeed: `:remote connect tinkerpop.server conf/remote.yaml` it does not mean that you have a connection. The actual "connection" is only established after you try to send a request, so that error is typically indicative of some kind of network failure or server configuration error.

Comment: Yes, I agree. Thanks.

Answer (score 1):

Some people might be confused by this, but if you are trying to run the commands locally and you get this error, run `:remote console` and the error should go away.

Source: https://docs.datastax.com/en/dse/5.1/dse-dev/datastax_enterprise/graph/using/QuickStartGremlin.html